# (hadoop.pig) multiple counts in single table

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

So, I have a data that has two values, string, and a number.

```
data(string:chararray, number:int)
```

and I am counting in 5 different rules,

1: int being 0~1.

2: int being 1~2.

~

5: int being 4~5.

So I was able to count them individually,

```
zero_to_one = filter avg_user by average_stars >= 0 and average_stars <= 1;
A = GROUP zero_to_one ALL;
zto_count = FOREACH A GENERATE COUNT(zero_to_one);

one_to_two = filter avg_user by average_stars > 1 and average_stars <= 2;
B = GROUP one_to_two ALL;
ott_count = FOREACH B GENERATE COUNT(one_to_two);

two_to_three = filter avg_user by average_stars > 2 and average_stars <= 3;
C = GROUP two_to_three ALL;
ttt_count = FOREACH C GENERATE COUNT( two_to_three);

three_to_four = filter avg_user by average_stars > 3 and average_stars <= 4;
D = GROUP three_to_four ALL;
ttf_count = FOREACH D GENERATE COUNT( three_to_four);

four_to_five = filter avg_user by average_stars > 4 and average_stars <= 5;
E = GROUP four_to_five ALL;
ftf_count = FOREACH E GENERATE COUNT( four_to_five);
```

So, this can be done, but 
this only results in 5 individual table.

I want to see if there is any way (is ok to be fancy, I love fancy stuff)
T can make the result in single table.

Which means if

```
zto_count = 1
ott_count = 3
. = 2
. = 3
. = 5
```

then the table will be {1,3,2,3,5}

It just is easy to parse data, and organize them that way.

Is there any ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this as input:

```
foo 2
foo 3
foo 2
foo 3
foo 5
foo 4
foo 0
foo 4
foo 4
foo 5
foo 1
foo 5
```

(0 and 1 each appear once, 2 and 3 each appear twice, 4 and 5 each appear thrice)

This script:

```
A = LOAD 'myData' USING PigStorage(' ') AS (name: chararray, number: int);

B = FOREACH (GROUP A BY number) GENERATE group AS number, COUNT(A) AS count ;

C = FOREACH (GROUP B ALL) {
    zto = FOREACH B GENERATE (number==0?count:0) + (number==1?count:0) ;
    ott = FOREACH B GENERATE (number==1?count:0) + (number==2?count:0) ;
    ttt = FOREACH B GENERATE (number==2?count:0) + (number==3?count:0) ;
    ttf = FOREACH B GENERATE (number==3?count:0) + (number==4?count:0) ;
    ftf = FOREACH B GENERATE (number==4?count:0) + (number==5?count:0) ;
    GENERATE SUM(zto) AS zto,
             SUM(ott) AS ott,
             SUM(ttt) AS ttt,
             SUM(ttf) AS ttf,
             SUM(ftf) AS ftf ;
}
```

Produces this output:

```
C: {zto: long,ott: long,ttt: long,ttf: long,ftf: long}
(2,3,4,5,6)
```

The number of FOREACHs in C shouldn't really matter because C is going to only have 5 elements at most, but if it is then then they can be put together like this:

```
C = FOREACH (GROUP B ALL) {
    total = FOREACH B GENERATE (number==0?count:0) + (number==1?count:0) AS zto,
                               (number==1?count:0) + (number==2?count:0) AS ott,
                               (number==2?count:0) + (number==3?count:0) AS ttt,
                               (number==3?count:0) + (number==4?count:0) AS ttf,
                               (number==4?count:0) + (number==5?count:0) AS ftf ;
    GENERATE SUM(total.zto) AS zto,
             SUM(total.ott) AS ott,
             SUM(total.ttt) AS ttt,
             SUM(total.ttf) AS ttf,
             SUM(total.ftf) AS ftf ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much mr2ert. I think i figured everything out now. I appreciate your help!

Comment: One thing you didnt show is that this code will only cover datas if the data has no decimal, but since there was no specification on my part stating that data may have decimal( i said int, which was my mistake) , your answer is perfect. I can fix that part. Thank you so much!